# Scoped NPM Package binaries not added to PATH

Tags: node.js, npm

Using new NPM private packages, with a scope package. However, when installing, the projects bin is lo longer added to path.

This works, with the tool available in the PATH.

```
{
 name: 'hello',
 bin: { 'hello':'hello.js' }
}
```

This does not work, once the scope has been added.

```
{
 name: '@private/hello',
 bin: { 'hello':'hello.js' }
}
```

Error is:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/hello: No such file or directory
```

Does the bin path need to change?

Update: What `npm link` does:

```
/usr/local/bin/hello -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@private/hello/hello.js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@private/hello -> /Path/To/HomeDirectory/SourceFolder.git
```

Comment: Could you show the output of `npm link` when executed in a scoped package directory?

Comment: @eush77 `npm link` seems to fix the issue and the binary can be found and run (see output in updated question). Although it needed to be run from inside the source folder. Installing via npm private has the same issue unless the user goes and finds the folder manually. File on GitHub as npm bug?

Comment: I think it is an npm bug indeed. https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders says executables for global installs should go to `{prefix}/bin` and in this case they certainly do not.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me.

```
$ cat package.json
{"name":"@isaacs/foo","bin":{"foo":"foo.js"},"version":"1.2.3"}

$ npm link
/usr/local/bin/foo -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@isaacs/foo/foo.js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@isaacs/foo -> /Users/isaacs/dev/js/x/scopebin

$ foo
foo

$ cat $(which foo)
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log("foo")

$ ls -laF $(which foo)
lrwxr-xr-x  1 isaacs  admin  38 Jun 22 15:55 /usr/local/bin/foo@ -> ../lib/node_modules/@isaacs/foo/foo.js

$ ls -laF /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@isaacs/foo
lrwxr-xr-x  1 isaacs  admin  31 Jun 22 15:55 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@isaacs/foo@ -> /Users/isaacs/dev/js/x/scopebin
```

Of course, if you use just `"bin":"foo.js"` in your package.json, then the default mechanism of turning that into `"bin":{<package name>:"foo.js"}` won't work, because the `<package name>` has a `/` in it.

```
$ npm link
/usr/local/bin/@isaacs/foo -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@isaacs/foo/foo.js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@isaacs/foo -> /Users/isaacs/dev/js/x/scopebin
```

Since `/usr/local/bin/@isaacs` isn't in my `PATH`, it won't work as expected.

```
$ foo
bash: foo: command not found
```

This is using the latest and greatest npm.  YMMV if you're using something older.

```
$ npm -v
2.12.0
```

Comment: The `npm link` command does work, however, this is installing the tool from npm private, so `npm install foo -g`. This npm install command doesn't seem to link the binary. If 'foo' were not scoped, the npm install command works normally.